# Typescript compile error even though parameters are of the correct type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Typescript throws this compile error:

```
Argument of type '(state: string, action: Action<string>) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<string, Action<string>>'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2345
```

and my function looks like this:

```
function todos(state: string, action: Action<string>)
```

What I can't understand is, first, the `state` parameter is not nullable yet the compiler says it's nullable. Second, the error message contradicts itself by saying in the first line that the function's type is `(state: string, action: Action<string>) => string` (which is correct) whereas the third line is saying that the first parameter is `string | undefined`!

I'm just beginning learning typescript and react-redux so I'm really confused.

**EDIT:**

Further, I tried calling the function passing `undefined` as first argument but the compiler complains that it's not nullable as expected, yet complain later that it's nullable!

**EDIT 2**

I forgot to say that I'm using the `todos` function in calling the `createStore` function from redux like this: `createStore(todos)`.

The full code is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './styles/index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {Action, createStore} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from "react-redux";

function todos(state: string, action: Action<string>) {
    return state
}

let store = createStore(todos); // PROBLEM HERE
let app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers:
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Also, I'm aware that `combineReducers` is normally used and that `state` shouldn't be a `string`, but I'm asking this question purely out of curiosity (being a beginner in typescript) because I know that there are obvious workarounds.

I also tried using `string[]` as the type of the state but same error is thrown except that it's `string[] | undefined` at this time.

**EDIT 3:**

I realized that if I add a default value to the state, e.g. `function todos(state: string = "", action: Action)`, the error will be gone. But why is this? Isn't it redundant given that state is already a required, non-nullable parameter? In Swift and Kotlin, the error will be thrown only if you call the `todos` function with a nil state argument, but you don't need to provide a default value in the definition of the parameter. So why is this the case in typescript? Is this by design?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've shared all relevant code here... the error is in some function that takes `todos` as a parameter to something, but all you've shown here is the signature of `todos` and not the signature of the function.  Ideally you should work to provide a [mcve], preferably one where you can link to an online IDE like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/).  The easier you make it for others to reproduce your error and modify your code, the likelier it will be for you to get a satisfactory answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi @jcalz, sorry I forgot to add some info. I just edited the question and added more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your exact question mentioned in EDIT 3 making function parameter default (as you did by specifing default value for `state`) changes type of such parameter to `string | undefined` (in your case). This also eqvivalent to question mark after parameter. So call signatures of three functions below are the same

```
function todos(state: string | undefined, action: Action<string>)
function todos(state?: string, action: Action<string>)  // This example is not completly correct as you should make action optional too, by addint ? to it name
function todos(state: string = "", action: Action<string>)
```

I suggest this [chapter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters) from Typescript doc.

Error in the start of this topic states that `Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.` So adding default value to `state` makes it of type `string | undefined` which satisfied compiler.

Comment: That seems right. I actually tested that (the second case only and I didn't bother checking the first since I thought they're just equivalent) but I got thrown off because the second case produced another error (i.e. TS1016). I think this inconsistency should be fixed because it's misleading.